# Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 607631544 bytes)

Tags: php, wordpress

After a Zend Server upgrade, I've been getting these random Internal Server Errors.  (hit refresh a few times, and it goes away).

My Wordpress debug.log shows:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 607631544 bytes) in C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.mywebsite.com\wp-content\plugins\cookie-notice\cookie-notice.php on line 1299
```

I looked on Stack overflow, and I noticed other people have had similar questions.  (same error message, but different number of bytes).

In those other questions, the solution was to increase the maximum allowable number of bytes.  In my situation, the number of bytes is extremely large (several GBs).  There's no way my pages should be using so much space.

In my situation, the specific error message refers to a specific plugin.  However, if I remove that Wordpress plugin, I just get the same error message referring to another plugin.  Therefore, I'm not sure if it's really the plugin that's causing the issue.

My stack trace looks like this:

```
 Cookie_Notice() at C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.mySite.com\wp-content\plugins\cookie-notice\cookie-notice.php: 1299
 main() at C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.mySite.com\wp-content\plugins\cookie-notice\cookie-notice.php: 1308
 main() at C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.mySite.com\wp-settings.php: 428
 main() at C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.mySite.com\wp-config.php: 112
 main() at C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.mySite.com\wp-load.php: 50
 main() at C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.mySite.com\wp-blog-header.php: 13
 main() at C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.mySite.com\index.php: 17
```

I reviewd the plugin, and it looks like this:
/**

- Initialize Cookie Notice.
  */

  function Cookie_Notice() {
  static $instance;   //THIS IS LINE 1299

  ```
   // first call to instance() initializes the plugin
   if ( $instance === null || ! ( $instance instanceof Cookie_Notice ) )
       $instance = Cookie_Notice::instance();

   return $instance;
  ```

  }

At first, I thought maybe that plugin is bad, so I removed the entire plugin.  But then, I just get the same error for another plugin:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4230139628 bytes) in C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.myWebsite.com\wp-content\plugins\wp-mail-smtp\wp-mail-smtp.php on line 55
```

Line 55 looks like this:

```
function wp_mail_smtp() {
    /**
     * @var \WPMailSMTP\Core
     */
    static $core;   //LINE 55 is here

    if ( ! isset( $core ) ) {
        $core = new \WPMailSMTP\Core();
    }

    return $core;
}
```

The stack track looks like this:

```
 wp_mail_smtp() at C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.myWebsite.com\wp-content\plugins\wp-mail-smtp\wp-mail-smtp.php: 55
 main() at C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.myWebsite.com\wp-content\plugins\wp-mail-smtp\wp-mail-smtp.php: 64
 main() at C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.myWebsite.com\wp-content\plugins\wp-mail-smtp\wp_mail_smtp.php: 303
 main() at C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.myWebsite.com\wp-settings.php: 428
 main() at C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.myWebsite.com\wp-config.php: 112
 main() at C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.myWebsite.com\wp-load.php: 50
 main() at C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.myWebsite.com\wp-blog-header.php: 13
 main() at C:\MyWebsite\htdocs\website.myWebsite.com\index.php: 17
```

So far, it looks like $static variables are crashing my server?  Any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score -1):

you php installation is using more ram than permitted size. So you should increase memory size in your php.ini and restart xampp.

[image]

Comment: I understand that's what the error message says, but something just doesn't line up.  First, the amount of memory in that error message seems to fluctuate.  Sometimes, it asks for 3.7GB, when my site has always run on 512MB.  All I did was upgrade my Zend Stack, and now it needs a 7-fold increase in memory.  Also, the error message seems to stem from a line of code that's declaring a static instance of a small class, which shouldn't take GBs of memory.